# Segmentation Fault when creating AllJoyn BusAttachment

Tags: c++, raspbian, alljoyn

I have built the latest Alljoyn sdk (version 16.04a) on Raspbian and generated the liballjoyn.so and liballjoyn.a without any errors or issues. Scons cmd: scons OS=linux CPU=arm OE_BASE=/usr BINDINGS=cpp BR=on BT=off ICE=off WS=off SERVICES="about" CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

So in my program, which is a really simple one and just has several lines to create a busattachment.

When I started debugging, it threw a "Segmentation Fault" in a STL class. 
I ran Valgrind to see what actually the problem is, and the result is something about "invalid read size of 4".

Any ideas? Did I miss anything during the building process? Or do I need to do anything with my codes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Elf needs code ([mcve]) badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is really a silly one... it ends up with I did not initialize Alljoyn correctly: I missed the AllJoynInit() method.